# how to link array element to a string

Tags: php

The following instruction  -

```
$this->menuTablesArr[$i]."_tablelink_attrs"
```

works correctly in older versions but in PHP5 it gives this error:

> error type 8 Array to string conversion

Could anyone help ?  many thanks

Comment: `var_dump($this->menuTablesArr[$i]);` is this a string?

Answer (score 0):

In your question isn't clear, what you mean by "works correctly". What is the outcome, when it works correctly?
I will assume, that this error is due to concatenating array and string. It can solve PHP function [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php). This function can have one or two parameters.

In your case you can use it e.g. with only one parameter

```
implode($this->menuTablesArr[$i])."_tablelink_attrs"
```

If you want to use some glue between items of array, you can use two parameters. More documentation about this function is in the link above.

Comment: when the value of $i is 0 (first element of the array)

Comment: when the value of $i is 0 (first element of array)  the content of menuTablesArr[$i] obtained with var_dump is     array(3) { ["shortTName"]=> string(6) "scheda" ["dataSourceTName"]=> string(6) "scheda" ["nType"]=> int(0) }   I'm afraid this is not my code and I haven't got any documentation about it.

Comment: The strange thing  is that in very olf environment (like, for example, EasyPHP 1.8)  the instruction is correctly executed, while in later versions (e.g.  EasyPHP Devserver 16.1.1) it doesn't work.   Anyway, the complete instruction is:  $this->xt->assign($this->menuTablesArr[$i]."_tablelink_attrs", "href=\"".$this->menuTablesArr[$i]."_".$page.".php\"");

Comment: the function assign is the following:   function assign($name,$val)
{
 $this->xt_vars[$name]=$val;
}

Comment: sorry, I'm afraid I know no more to help.  Thanks for support

Comment: Strange idea: could it be possible that, also in older environments, the instruction could generate error but for particular settings it is ignored?

Comment: Did you try the `implode` function, as I proposed? Yes, it is possible, that instuction generated error, but error was ignored. It depends on settings [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and [`display_errors`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors). You can setup these variables in `php.ini`, in `.htaccess` or directly in your php code. It is possible, that in previous environment of php had these variables different values.

Comment: Dear von Oak, I used your suggestion and obtained a result, meaning that non more errors are displayed. Seemingly, I can't see any different behaviour between the both situations, so I can consider (hopely) the problem as solved. I'll inform you for eventual forthcoming news.

Comment: Good:-) In that case the error was most likely also on old environment, but was ignored due to different configuration.